# how to remove wp admin menu created by plugin

Tags: admin-menu

actually i want to remove instantsearch+ link from wp admin bar but i don't have the proper slug for this. when i mouseover on this link , it shows https://woo.instantsearchplus.com/wc_dashboard?site_id=0d9a1252-c38d-4191-9ff2-14adc3e75b90&authentication_key=ag1zfmFjcC1tYWdlbnRvchoLEg1BTV9TaXRlX0dyb3VwGICA8N_59csIDA&new_tab=1&v=1.7.1&store_id=1&site=http://localhost/rowsandracks
 on the bottom.[image]
i have attached the image below .

Comment: in this plugin code, search add_menu_page() and comment this code, this link will be hide from the menu.

Comment: Hi, do you mind if you use css to hide the item?

Comment: @ fmeaddons thank u for your comment. i comment this and it fixed. thank u.